# How to read push notifications from other apps in iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, push-notification, apple-push-notifications, pebble-watch

I wanted to know how to be able to read and get the contents of another app's push notification in iOS. Such as a push notification from Facebook Messenger, or Twitter.

I know this is possible because that is exactly what the Pebble Smartwatch iOS app does. It intercepts the push notifications of the iPhone and sends them to the smartwatch over Bluetooth.

Answer (score 5):

Devices such as the Pebble, use the [ANCS service](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/CoreBluetooth/Reference/AppleNotificationCenterServiceSpecification/Introduction/Introduction.html) with Bluetooth.  An app cannot directly access the notifications for/from other apps.

Comment: This may be one way - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32334153/how-to-catch-all-push-notifications-from-other-apps-on-ios-using-private-framewo