# How to read notifications in React Native?

Tags: react-native

I am building an app with a use case where I will have to read the notifications of other apps to get the information about the media which is playing currently (like song name, artist name, etc).

How do I achieve this on React Native? I have no idea where to start.

Comment: I don't think reading notification across apps is possible on [iOS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41420432/is-it-possible-to-intercept-push-notifications-for-another-app), on Android you can could try this library: [react-native-android-notification-listener](https://github.com/leandrosimoes/react-native-android-notification-listener) or write your own native module.

Comment: Did you find a way for ios?